# Type A is already defined error

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to search for the solution, but what I found I don't know how to apply in this situation. Please help me correct my code.

```
package Exercise;

public class Ex11_11 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A(3);
    }
}

class A extends B { // type A is already defined, A has a red underline
    public A (int t) {
    System.out.println("A's constructor is invoked");
    }
}

class B { // type B is already defined, B has a red underline
    public B () {
        System.out.println("B's constructor is invoked");
    }  
}
```

Comment: do you have another class with name `A` in the same package ?

Comment: Do you have other classes in the same package?

Comment: I had a class with the name A in the same package.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, the first thing to check is obviously whether or not you have another class called `A` in your file or in the same package.

Comment: in eclipse, we can have several source folders on a single project, if the file have the same path structure and name etc, it will conflict, thx!

Answer (score 37):

Eclipse sometimes gets confused. If you choose `Clean` from the `Project` menu, it might fix these errors.

Comment: And sometimes it isn't confused. I'm going with Jigar and PM's suggestion -- that there are other A and B classes visible in the same namespace.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  My computer was restarted remotely by I.T, and Eclipse did not shut down gracefully.  I noticed there was an extra java file in my project that I didn't add.   Deleted it, and now the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

In Project-> Clean,  select "Clean projects selected below", select my project(s) and check "Start a build immediately" with "Build only selected projects".

Then problem will resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Check if all your class files are saved. I've had this problem a few times: i define a class in a class file then move it in it's own one. Java gets confised, because it reads from the old version of the original file. Once you save it with the missing class definition in it and define the class in the new file all should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

In your project you might have test directory with the same package structure and the same class name (for example copied without changing class name to *Test).

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above solutions worked for you then it possible that Build Path is messed up. When you add a src to the build path make sure the src is not in the exclusion list. Place *(wild card) in the inclusion list and nothing in the exclusion list.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure

> Project | Build Automatically

is checked.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this is that somewhere in same package you have already defined a class with name A.
which causes type **A** is already defined error.

check if there is any subclass or inner class named **A**

Answer (score 0):

Have you added another project to the build path?

I had the same issue on my development environment (Eclipse). 
My Maven application consumed other applications. On Eclipse, those projects were just added to the build path. One of them had the same package structure and class filename. Eclipse ends up thinking both the files which are physically different are in the same directory since the package structure and filename are same. 
For example, let's say there are two files as below:

```
/Users/uname/home/proj1/com/app/proj/main/java/util/file1.java
```

and

```
/Users/uname/home/proj2/com/app/proj/main/java/util/file1.java
```

and lets say both have the package name

```
com.app.define.proj.util
```

If you add one of the project to the other, Eclipse would consider both the files to be in the same location. 

I resolved by creating a JAR file out of the consumed application, adding it to the build path and removing the Eclipse project from build path.

Answer (score 0):

rename the class name A to Aa or something and try to run.